# Making a directory from multiple files in python

Tags: python

I am stuck with an intermediate step in my code, where it takes a number of input files from the user (the number of input files are dependent on user and are not fixed) and makes a directory out of these files as an example the input files will look like as given below:

Input file1:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5    COL6    COL7    COL8    COL9
NM_032291   chr1    66999824    67210768                    1.4612e+01
NM_001080397    chr1    8384389 8404227                 1.0545e+01
NM_018090   chr1    16767166    16786584                    1.4473e+01
NM_032785   chr1    48998526    50489626                    5.4473e-01
NM_001145278    chr1    16767166    16786584                    1.0545e+02
NM_013943   chr1    25071759    25170815                    1.473e-04
NM_001145277    chr1    16767166    16786584                    1.4473e+01
NM_052998   chr1    33546713    33585995                    1.4473e+02
NM_001195683    chr1    92145899    92351836                    1.4473e+03
```

Input file2:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5    COL6    COL7    COL8    COL9
NM_032291   chr1    66999824    67210768                    1.473e-04
NM_001080397    chr1    8384389 8404227                 1.473e-03
NM_018090   chr1    16767166    16786584                    1.473e-02
NM_032785   chr1    48998526    50489626                    1.473e-01
NM_001145278    chr1    16767166    16786584                    1.473e00
NM_013943   chr1    25071759    25170815                    1.473e01
NM_001145277    chr1    16767166    16786584                    1.473e02
NM_052998   chr1    33546713    33585995                    1.473e03
NM_001195683    chr1    92145899    92351836                    1.473e04
```

I am concerned only with the values in column1 and in last column of each file the identifiers and their order in column1 is fixed across all input files. while the value in last column of each file is changing. Rest of the columns are not interesting and can have any value.

What I want is a final file which looks like this:

```
NM_032291   1.4612e+01  1.473e-04
NM_001080397    1.0545e+01  1.473e-03
NM_018090   1.4473e+01  1.473e-02
NM_032785   5.4473e-01  1.473e-01
NM_001145278    1.0545e+02  1.473e00
NM_013943   1.473e-04   1.473e01
NM_001145277    1.4473e+01  1.473e02
NM_052998   1.4473e+02  1.473e03
NM_001195683    1.4473e+03  1.473e04
```

Of course there are three columns as there are only two input files, but in the case of three files it would be four and so on.

Comment: What have you tried? What were the errors? Where's the proof that you tried?

Comment: I tried to take the input as comma seperated and then running a loop but after that I was lost as to how I can extract the columns from each file and olace them in dictionary one after the other.

Comment: Again, edit your question, with your **code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data1 = ... # contents of file1
data2 = ... # contents of file2

data = [data1, data2]
# use [1:] to filter column headers
data_cells = [[line.split() for line in datum.split('\n')][1:]
              for datum in data]

result = []
for line_sequence in zip(*data_cells):
    col1 = line_sequence[0][0] # get row header
    result.append([col1]) # and put it in a list
    for line in line_sequence:
        result[-1].append(line[-1])

out = '\n'.join(['    '.join(line) for line in result])
print(out)
```

Result:

```
NM_032291    1.4612e+01    1.473e-04
NM_001080397    1.0545e+01    1.473e-03
NM_018090    1.4473e+01    1.473e-02
NM_032785    5.4473e-01    1.473e-01
NM_001145278    1.0545e+02    1.473e00
NM_013943    1.473e-04    1.473e01
NM_001145277    1.4473e+01    1.473e02
NM_052998    1.4473e+02    1.473e03
NM_001195683    1.4473e+03    1.473e04
```

This will extend to arbitrarily many rows and arbitrarily many files, provided that the guarantees you made about the data (order in column1 fixed, and you only care about the first and last columns of each row) are true.

Answer (score 1):

In places like this Numpy arrays comes in handy, especially the `T` method. This along with the `append` method is probably your best bet ...

So lets say, your files are in a list

```
files = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
```

etc...

Then, from each file, you only need the the last col (for now). A function to do that is pretty simple ...

```
def rdFl(fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        f.readline() # get rid of the header ...
        lst = [ float(l.split()[-1])  for l in f.readlines()]

    return lst
```

Now, for getting values from all files, simply map this function over all the files, like so:

```
allLastData = map(rdFl, files)
```

This will give you a list of lists containing all the numbers in the last col. What you want is the transpose of this list. So convert it into a NumPy array and take the transpose, like so (assuming you have done `import numpy as np`):

```
allLastData = np.array( map(rdFl, files) ).T
```

At this time look at `allLastData` on the terminal and you will understand what I am talking about. I hope I dont have to write a function that will give you the first column from just one file. I assume that you can write that function on your own. So let us say that you have the first column in the following list:

```
firstCol = ['NM_032291', ..., ...]
```

Then you can iterate over a zipped value of `firstCol` and `allData` like so:

```
for fV, dat in zip(firstCol, allLastData):
    print fv + '\t' + '\t'.join( map(str, dat) )
```

Here, I just wrote the code for printing. I am sure you can take the string and write it to a file instead.